# IdHttpServerexception:Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol;

Tags: delphi, openssl

I have a Delphi 2007 **TIdHttpServer** Web App (Version 10).  My **IdHTTPServer1.onexception** handler is handling a lot of these exceptions:

> Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was observed that violates
>   the protocol

I also have the latest version of OpenSSL (1.0.2.4).

I know it is protocol to have a MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example).  However I am not able to replicate this.  These exceptions are occurring in production environment.  All I have been able to do is log the ip address.  And the IP Addresses are random.  So it does not appear to be any single "spam bot" that could be doing this.

Do these exceptions mean something is making requests using a version of SSL that I am not supporting?

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Or is this something I should not worry about?

Below is my code for setting up the server:

```
ServerIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(self);
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'C:\xxxxx.crt';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'C:\xxxxx.key';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'C:\yyyyyyy.crt';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv23,sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
ServerIOHandler.OnGetPassword :=  GetSSLPassword;
IdHTTPServer1 := TEAIdHTTPServer.Create;
IdHTTPServer1.MaxConnections := 1000;
IdHTTPServer1.AutoStartSession := True;
IdHTTPServer1.SessionState := True;
IdHTTPServer1.OnCommandGet := MainGet;
IdHTTPServer1.onexception := IdHttpServerexception;
IdHTTPServer1.onlistenexception := IdHttpServerlistenexception;
IdHTTPServer1.onconnect := IdHttpServerConnect;
IdHTTPServer1.ondisconnect := IdHttpServerDisconnect;
idHttpServer1.ParseParams := True;
idHttpServer1.OnQuerySSLPort := QuerySSLPort;
idHttpServer1.IOHandler := ServerIOHandler;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;
IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;


procedure TMyProject.QuerySSLPort(APort: TIdPort; var VUseSSL: Boolean);
begin
  if APort=80 then begin
    vUseSSL := False;
  end else if APort=443 then begin
    vUseSSL := True;
  end else begin
    vUseSSL := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't answer your question, but your `QuerySSLPort` could be simplified to `VUseSLL := (APort = 443);`.

Comment: Yeah - it is that way because the original code had some other things going on.

Comment: You do not need to set both `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions`, they are mutually exclusive, setting one updates the other. `Method` is deprecated, stick with `SSLVersions`. You do not need to include `sslvSSLv23` in `SSLVersions`, and for security reasons you should omit `sslvSSLv2` and maybe `sslvSSLv3` as well. Everything else looks fine. The EOF error most likely means the client disconnected during the SSL handshaking. I would ignore it on the server side, the connection is incomplete anyway. If you have clients that are complaining about it, then you can debug it further.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - ok - thank you.  When there is a disconnect during the handshaking, do most browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) typically try again afterwards?  If you convert to answer I will mark as accepted.